# Connection between fractional charge and Schrodinger's cat

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, quantum-hall-effect

In the FQHE, it is said that one electron splits into three 1/3-charged entities. Is it like the Schrodinger cat?

Comment: What is the FQHE?

Comment: Schroedinger's cat is pretty much just nonsense and there are no electrons in the fractional quantum hall effect. Instead you have quasi-particle states which carry a fraction of the electron's charge.

Comment: could you be more explicit? what would be the analogy?

Comment: did you read the wiki article on FQHE? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_quantum_Hall_effect

Answer (score 2):

> [The fractional quantum Hall effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_quantum_Hall_effect) (FQHE) is a physical phenomenon in which the Hall conductance of 2D electrons shows precisely quantised plateaus at fractional values of  e^2/h . It is a property of a collective state in which electrons bind magnetic flux lines to make new quasiparticles, and excitations have a fractional elementary charge and possibly also fractional statistics.

It is a quantized state   on the Hall conductance which emerges from a large number of electrons.

Schrodinger's cat is a  confusing and outdated example of the probabilistic nature of quantum mechanics .  The only connection FQHE has with Shrodinger's cat is that both depend on a quantum mechanical solution of a boundary value problem. It should be well known that quantum mechanical solutions give probability distribution for the outcome.